# CPU reaches 100% and most worker threads hang after hours of successful runtime, could be reqwest / tokio related

Tags: rust

I'm battling a 'deadlock' that makes me lose all hope. My program is bit too long so here's overlook:

- I'm spawning multiple worker threads through `tokio::spawn`
- all of them find similar data, and in the args of the function spawned receive a `mpsc` channel passed into args like this: `snd_a.clone()` (I hope that's fine and `Arc<Mutex<...>>` is not necessary?)
- receiver thread gets a `Receiver` handle `rcv_a` and further operates on the data that those threads pass to it - mostly through making calls described below.

There are more threads - relevant to the issue is one or two more that work outside of the above schematic but operate on the same shared data, mostly through `Mutex`es - where I believe they all fail is when the receiver and few more make `reqwest` calls on the data receiver gets. This is my `try_poll` function:

```
async fn try_poll(link:String, req_client: &Client, params: &[(&str, &str)]) -> Result<String, MyError> {
    println!("{:?}",line!());
    let res = match timeout(Duration::from_secs(10),req_client.get(link).query(params).send()).await{
        Ok(x)=> match x{
            Ok(x)=> match timeout(Duration::from_secs(10), x.text()).await{
                Ok(x)=> match x{
                    Ok(x)=> x,
                    Err(x)=>{
                        println!("--[tp 0]{:?}",x);
                        return Err(MyError::ReqwestFail)
                    }
                },
                Err(x)=>{
                    println!("--[tp 1]{:?}",x);
                    return Err(MyError::ReqwestFail)
                }
            },
            Err(x)=>{
                println!("--[tp 2]{:?}",x);
                return Err(MyError::ReqwestFail)
            }
        },
        Err(x)=> {
            println!("--[tp 3]{:?}",x);
            return Err(MyError::ReqwestFail)
        }
    };
    println!("{:?}",line!());
    Ok(res)
}
```

I've traced both:

- all lines executed and
- some lines executed

From around 15-20 monitored times it hanged, there was not much consistency in when and how, but so far, most often than not this is related to the above function.

Hanging looks like this: suddenly all worker threads hang & CPU locks at 100% and receiver & other call-making threads hang, everything but threads that are totally separate.

At least 2 times before the program hanged one thread executed the line of calling the above function, and then program hanged the exact moment a different thread called same reqwest's function parallely. So both hanged at first line of the function, without timeouts and anything, just the 100% CPU...and hangs.

At least 10 times the program hanged, the last line printed out was the first line of the above function (that prints the line before making the call) - there was no other output, no error, no timeout, no error in **multiple** error handling and retry loops I've put around that function... similarly as here - in some of the github issues people complain about the same thing. Is that a `reqwest` bug? One person mentioned `reqwest` co-ops with `std` not `tokio` so maybe that's the problem?

[Deadlock on execute possibly tied to a remote rate limit](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/issues/926)

[Program is stuck after calling .text() on Response in WSL 2](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/issues/1604)

[Hangs with blocking feature if response content-length: bytes is longer than actual body](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/issues/1646)

[Requests can hang indefinitely when using HTTP/2](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/issues/1323)

I'm guessing one of the APIs called hang indefinitely, there is no timeout at all. I can't figure out why threads that just should do worker stuff, find and pass data - WITHOUT making such calls hang as well - is that because of the 100% CPU lock? It reaches maximum and stays that way indefinitely. There's nothing to indicate the `mpsc` channel clogs.  When I call through my UI in the program something unrelated it executes always, it's just the backend workers / callmakers threads that hang on 100% CPU.

Can I somehow get to know literally everything that is executing, and figure out exactly what makes the CPU reach 100% all of a sudden? I need to know the operation names.

The fact there is no complete consistency as to how/where it hangs makes me totally depressed about this issue. As I said mostly it seems to hang on a non-timing-out reqwest call. Any help debugging it is immensely appreciated.

**-edit**

I've run a few commands reccomended on the Internet on the process just after it stuck, but have not much clue what the output means.

```
 Performance counter stats for process id '232825':

 472 004,37 msec task-clock                #    3,698 CPUs utilized          
 116 359      context-switches          #    0,247 K/sec                  
 1 058      cpu-migrations            #    0,002 K/sec                  
 917      page-faults               #    0,002 K/sec                  
 1 995 523 580 533      cycles                    #    4,228 GHz                    
 1 425 266 118 862      stalled-cycles-frontend   #   71,42% frontend cycles idle   
 987 982 567 869      stalled-cycles-backend    #   49,51% backend cycles idle    
 1 285 536 694 249      instructions              #    0,64  insn per cycle         
                                                  #    1,11  stalled cycles per insn
 240 695 202 055      branches                  #  509,943 M/sec                  
 5 222 709 470      branch-misses             #    2,17% of all branches        

 127,641810678 seconds time elapsed
```

```
strace: Process 232825 attached with 16 threads
[pid 239382] futex(0x7f7990027968, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 4294967295, NULL, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY <unfinished ...>
[pid 239377] restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted read ...> <unfinished ...>
[pid 239376] futex(0x5585fc023c98, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 239375] futex(0x5585fc0233e0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 239374] futex(0x5585fc0233e0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 239373] futex(0x5585fc0233e0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 239372] futex(0x5585fc0233e0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 239371] futex(0x5585fbfb6b0c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 239370] futex(0x5585fbfb69ac, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 239369] futex(0x5585fbfb684c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 239368] futex(0x5585fbfb66ec, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 232825] recvmsg(10, {msg_namelen=0}, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
[pid 232825] recvmsg(10, {msg_namelen=0}, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
[pid 232825] recvmsg(10, {msg_namelen=0}, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
[pid 232825] recvmsg(10, {msg_namelen=0}, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
[pid 232825] recvmsg(10, {msg_namelen=0}, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
[pid 232825] recvmsg(10, {msg_namelen=0}, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
[pid 232825] epoll_wait(11,
```

Comment: Have you dumped when it is hung and gotten stacktrace of all threads?

Comment: how can I do that?